# Evaluating $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+...}}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals

How would one evaluate the infinitely nested radical $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+...}}}}}}$$
due to the fact that each term cannot be evaluated individually to create a product or sum, and using repeated difference of two squares to find a pattern also doesn't seem to work, I am not sure where to even start. Any solutions or help would be appreciated

$$\text{it can be written as follows to make the pattern more obvious}$$
$$f(x) = \left(x+\left(x+\left(x+...\right)^{\frac{1}{8}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
and defined by the limit of the recursive sequence of functions (credit to @Andrea Marino)
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
f_1(x,y) & = & y^{1/2}\\
f_n(x,y) & = & f_{n - 1}(x,x + y^{1/2^n}) \textrm{ if } n \geqslant 1 \end{array}\right.
$$

update: This questions is bountied for anyone who can find a closed form, or at least an accurate approximation

Comment: Just approximation I think...  Is there an equation or is the expression solo, so $x$ has no boundaries aside from being non-negative?

Comment: For nonzero $x$, sufficiently "far" terms in the expression will be effectively $1$.

Comment: What is the pattern ?? You can make it look nicer and explain at once. 
I think $x^{2^{-n}}$ th root, but not sure.

Comment: @mick hope the edit helps

Comment: that is a bit better +1.

Comment: increasing and bounded serie, try to find by recurrence the limit

Comment: Maybe it helps to observe that if $f(x)$ is the function described, then $f(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{f(\sqrt x)}}$.

Comment: Seems harder than I thought, I tried to do this as a sequence and find something like u_n+2 = sqrt(u_n....u_n+1^1/2) or something like that (IDK), and apply the limit but it doesn't work

Comment: I think this is quite hopeless in a sense.  Maybe computing for a given x. But for general x I assume no closed form. This can not be done with sqrt or logs so ... We just get closer to " something ". Compare with $-1 + \exp(x/2) + \exp(x/4) + \exp(x/8) + \exp(x/16) + ...$

Comment: @GregMartin are you sure that this is doing what you wanted it to do?
It seems to me that $$f(\sqrt{x}) = \left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}+...\right)^{\frac{1}{8}}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ , right? so does that help?

Comment: Greg’s formula seems incorrect. You have isolated x terms with the entire expression having successfully more square roots. Doing square root of x doesn’t help do that.

Comment: Helpful observation, for anyone tackling this (also I think the question needs revising, the last part):

$$\sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+...}}}}}}}$$ is *not* the expression indicated here with the underbrace:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+...}}}}}}}$$

and same goes for $\sqrt{f(\sqrt{x})}$ for obvious reasons.

Comment: Given a sequence of functions $f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y), \dots$, the way one usually defines the expression $f_1(x,f_2(x,f_3(x,\dots)))$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_1(x,f_2(x,f_3(x,\dots f_n(x,a)\dots)))$. If the limit does not converge or if it changes with $a$ (which is limited by the domains of all the functions), then the expression is considered undefined. In this case, $a^{1/2^n} \to 1$, so the latter isn't an issue. I think the convergents are evenually decreasing and bounded below by $1$ (even when $x < 1$), but I haven't established that for sure.

Comment: It seems that $f(x)=x$ when $x=\sqrt{3.05...}$

Comment: Is there any way to use the fact that a sequence of functions that looks like:
$$f_1(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}$$
$$f_2(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\dots}}}}}}$$
$$f_3(x) = \sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\dots}}}}}}}$$
$$\dots$$
(Where I hope the pattern is clear) We have
$$f_{_{1}}^{{}{}2} - x = f_1$$
$$(f_{_{2}}^2-x)^4-x = f_2$$
$$\left((f_{_{3}}^2-x)^4-x\right)^8-x = f_3$$
$$\dots$$
I think that $f_n$ can be found for any finite $n$ (though the solutions become more complex..), can it be extended by some limiting process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem seems very interesting, I spent a bit of time on it and here is what I got. First of all, as said @Andrea Marino, this infinite root can be defined as the limit of the recursive sequence of functions,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
f_1(x,y) & = & y^{1/2}\\
f_n(x,y) & = & f_{n - 1}(x,x + y^{1/2^n}) \textrm{ if } n \geqslant 1 \end{array}\right.
$$
Here, $y$ represents the starting point of your sequence of roots. Andrea suggested that we start at $y = x$ but we will see actually that $f_n$ converges to a limit which doesn't depend on $y$.

Indeed, some numerical observations suggest that,
\begin{array}{l}
*\ f_n(x,y) \rightarrow f(x) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \textrm{ simply},\\
*\ \textrm{ The convergence is uniform on each } [\varepsilon,+\infty[,\\ 
*\ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = 1,\\
*\ f \textrm{ is smooth on } ]0,+\infty[,\\
*\ f \textrm{ increases}.
\end{array}
Notice that each $f_n$ is clearly increasing with respect to both $x$ and $y$ so the last point is trivial if we assume that $f$ exists.

To get easily the smoothness (and even the analyticity !), we can extend the domain of the $f_n$ on the whole $\mathbb{H}^2$ where $\mathbb{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}|\Re(z) > 0\} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}|-\pi/2 < \arg(z) < \pi/2\}$. Indeed, we can extend $m$-th roots on this set by $(re^{i\theta})^{1/m} = r^{1/m}e^{i\theta/m}$ where $\theta$ is chosen between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. This defined holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{H}$ to itself. Moreover, $\mathbb{H}$ is stable by sum, thus the $f_n$ are well defined since $(x,y) \in \mathbb{H}^2 \Rightarrow x + y^{1/2^n} \in \mathbb{H}$. We can even choose $x \in \overline{\mathbb{H}} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}|\Re(z) \geqslant 0\}$.

The purpose of doing this is to define $f$ on the whole $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ and to prove in the same time that it is holomorphic using theorems like Morera's theorem that is useful to show that a limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, thus we should obtain the highest possible level of smoothness for $f$. Finally, we can study the limit at $x = 0$.

**Lipschitzianity of the $f_n$**

First of all, let $\mathbb{H}_\varepsilon = \{z \in \mathbb{H}|\Re(z) \geqslant \varepsilon\}$. Let us prove that $f_n(x,\cdot)$ is $k_n(\varepsilon)$-Lipschitzian with respect to $y$ in $\mathbb{H}_\varepsilon$ where $k_n(\varepsilon)$ will be determined later. Recall that on $\mathbb{H}_\varepsilon$,
$$
\left|\frac{d}{dy}y^{1/m}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{m}y^{\frac{1}{m} - 1}\right| \leqslant m^{-1}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/m},
$$
thus $y \mapsto y^{1/m}$ is $m^{-1}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/m}$-Lipschitzian so in particular, $f_1(x,\cdot)$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$-Lipschitzian i.e. $k_1(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$ fits.

Now, if $y = re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{H}_\varepsilon$ with $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$, $y^{1/m} = r^{1/m}e^{i\theta/m}$. We deduce that $\Re(y) = r\cos(\theta) \geqslant \varepsilon$ so $r \geqslant \varepsilon$ and
$$
\Re(y^{1/m}) = r^{1/m}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{m}\right) \geqslant r^{1/m - 1}r\cos(\theta) \geqslant \varepsilon^{1/m - 1}\varepsilon = \varepsilon^{1/m}.
$$
Therefore, $x + y^{1/m} \in \mathbb{H}_{\varepsilon^{1/m}}$ hence by induction,
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x,y) - f_n(x,z)| & = |f_{n - 1}(x,x + y^{1/2^n}) - f_{n - 1}(x,x + z^{1/2^n})|\\
& \leqslant k_{n - 1}(\varepsilon^{1/2^n})|y^{1/2^n} - z^{1/2^n}|\\
& \leqslant k_{n - 1}(\varepsilon^{1/2^n})2^{-n}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/2^n}|y - z|.
\end{align*}
It show that indeed $f_n(x,\cdot)$ is $k_n(\varepsilon)$-Lipschiztian with $k_n(\varepsilon) = k_{n - 1}(\varepsilon^{1/2^n})2^{-n}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/2^n}$. Let us show by induction that we have the bound $k_n(\varepsilon) \leqslant 2^{-n(n + 1)/2}\varepsilon^{-1}$ when $\varepsilon \leqslant 1$. Indeed, $k_1(\varepsilon) = 2^{-1}\varepsilon^{-1/2} \leqslant 2^{-1}\varepsilon^{-1}$ and for all $n \geqslant 2$,
\begin{align*}
k_n(\varepsilon) & = k_{n - 1}(\varepsilon^{1/2^n})2^{-n}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/2^n}\\
& \leqslant 2^{-(n - 1)n/2}(\varepsilon^{1/2^n})^{-1}2^{-n}\varepsilon^{-1 + 1/2^n}\\
& \leqslant 2^{-n(n + 1)/2}\varepsilon^{-1}\\
\end{align*}
It shows in particular that $f_n(x,\cdot)$ is $\frac{1}{\varepsilon2^{n(n + 1)/2}}$-Lipschitzian which is a good sign that the limit of the $f_n$, if it exists, won't depend on $y$.

**Convergence of $f_n(\cdot,1)$**

By Lipschitzianity, we have that for all $n$ and all $x$,
$$
|f_n(x,1) - f_{n - 1}(x,1)| = |f_{n - 1}(x,x + 1) - f_{n - 1}(x,1)| \leqslant \frac{|x|}{2^{(n - 1)n/2}}.
$$
We deduce that $\sum f_n(\cdot,1) - f_{n - 1}(\cdot,1)$ converges normally on all compact subset of $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ because $\sum 2^{-(n - 1)n/2}$ converges. In particular, $f_n(x,1) \rightarrow f(x)$ when $n \rightarrow +\infty$ locally uniformly. Local uniform convergence preserves continuity and holomorphicness (it follows from Morera's theorem) thus $f$ is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ and holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$. Now, if we take a $y \in \mathbb{H}_\varepsilon$ for a $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 1$, we have,
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x,y) - f(x)| & \leqslant |f_n(x,y) - f_n(x,1)| + |f_n(x,1) - f(x)|\\
& \leqslant \frac{|y - 1|}{\varepsilon 2^{n(n + 1)/2}} + |f_n(x,1) - f(x)|\\
& \rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
and the convergence is uniform if we take $x$ in a compact subset of $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ and $y$ in a $\mathbb{H}_\varepsilon$ (in particular, we have uniform convergence on all compact subset of $\overline{\mathbb{H}} \times \mathbb{H}$). The limit doesn't depend on the choice of $y$.

**Discussion**

$*$ As we must have $\Re(y) > 0$, then for all $n$, $f_n(0,y) = y^{1/2^{n(n + 1)/2}} \rightarrow 1$ so $f(0) = 1$ and not $0$ as the expression with the imbricated square roots sugests it.

$*$ What happens if we replace $f_n(x,y) = f_{n - 1}(x,x + y^{1/2^n})$ by $f_n(x,y) = f_n(x,x + y^{a_n})$ for some sequence $a_n \in [0,1]$ ? In the proof of the convergence of $(f_n(\cdot,1))$, we needed the fact that $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} 2^{-n(n + 1)/2} < +\infty$ which probably becomes in this generalized case $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \prod_{k = 1}^n a_k < +\infty$.

$*$ Is is possible to continue $f$ on a larger domain of $\mathbb{C}$ ? Like for power functions, I think we can't continue $f$ on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ but maybe on any domain that doesn't contain $0$ and in which any loop has a null index around $0$.

Comment: Very nice! I was thinking if there is a possibility to compute the first terms of its Taylor expansion, by showing that the convergence is $C_k$ and then taking the limit of the derivatives in - say - 1. Do you think this is possible? We could have an approximation of the result in this way!

Comment: Good question, I continued observations and it looks like $f$ can be continued on some real interval $]-\alpha,+\infty[$ with $\alpha \approx 2/3$. Notice that in this case, and if the continuation is analytic, the last point of my discussions becomes wrong, but yes, maybe $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$. However, still with observations, it looks like $f$ is not derivable at $x = -\alpha$ hence the series $f(x) = \sum a_nx^n$ would have a convergence radius of $r \leqslant \alpha < 1$ so we can't deduce $f(1)$ with this method. And by the way, observations give $f(1) \approx 1.4842$.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can show that there is no analytical solution around zero to the GregMartin reformulation. Indeed, assume
$$ f(x) = \sum_n a_nx^n$$
Recall that
$$ \left (\sum_m b_m y^m\right )^2 = \sum_m y^m \sum_{i+j=m} b_i b_j $$
Using the equation, we can write
$$ \sum_n a_n x^n  = \sqrt{x+ \sqrt{ \sum_n a_n x^{n/2}  }}$$
Squaring as much as we can to get rid of square roots, we get
$$ \left (\left (\sum_n a_n x^n \right )^2 - x \right )^2  =\sum_n a_n x^{n/2}$$
Now consider
$$P(y) = \sum_n a_{2n}y^n, \ \ \ Q(y) =\sum_n a_{2n+1}y^n $$
with the coefficients taken from $f$ itself. We can continue to manipulate the equation to get
$$\left (\left (\sum_n a_n x^n \right )^2 - x \right )^2  =\sum_n a_n x^{n/2} = P(x)+ \sqrt{x}Q(x)$$
If $Q(x)$ was non zero, we could write $Q(x) = \alpha x^p \left( 1+ R(x) \right ) $ for some series $R(x)$ and $\alpha \neq 0$. Since $1+R(x)$ would be an invertible power series around zero, we could write
$$\frac{\left (\left (\sum_n a_n x^n \right )^2 - x \right )^2-P(x)}{\alpha(1+R(x) )} = x^p \sqrt{x}$$
which is impossible, since LHS is differentiable in $x=0$ while RHS is not. We conclude $Q(y) =0$. This means $f(x)$ has only even terms.

Now... repeating the same argument with $x=\sqrt{z}$, we will get that $f$ has only terms divisible by $4$. In general, if we set $k$ to be the least index for which there exists $a_{2^k d } \neq 0$ for some $d$, using the equation with $x=z^{1/2^k}$ will get us a contradiction.

**Why this is a problem?** It is not really a problem, just you will not get a closed 'nice' solution involving exponentials, trigonometric functions, powers, but even n-th roots and logarithms with argument $(1+t)$... It's still possible, however, that there is a solution involving n-th roots with argument $x$!!

Comment: The larger problem is that Greg's formulation isn't correct.  I always thought of the error as the "shrinking line" error: $\sqrt{x+b}$ becomes $\sqrt{x} + b$ as student's radicals shrink over their work.

Comment: and the professors shriek... :)

Comment: Nooooo that's right!! Ok here is it a possible recursive formulation. Set $g_1(x,y)=\sqrt{y}$ and then $g_{n+1}(x,y) = g_n(x,x+y^{1/2^{n+1}})$.  Our function is $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x,x)$. Does it converge nicely at least?