# Elliptic-Function Radical $R = x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\sqrt{x\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x...}}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, elliptic-functions

This post concerns a radical I included in an earlier post that didn't receive much attention, and I hypothesize that this radical has quite an interesting closed form, therefore I'm posting this.

(This, visually, is like the product equivalent of [this radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703760/evaluating-sqrtx-sqrt-sqrtx-sqrt-sqrt-sqrtx))

I will denote it $R$ and is defined as follows

$$R = x\sqrt{x\sqrt{\sqrt{x\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x...}}}}}}$$
Evaluating each term's powers we can see that
$$R = x\cdot x^{2^{-1}}\cdot x^{2^{-3}}\cdot x^{2^{-6}}\cdot x^{2^{-10}}...$$
The powers of 2 follow the sequence of triangle numbers and therefore,
$$R = x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$
$$ = x\cdot x^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$
The exponent of $x$ is the sum
$$1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$$
which seems like it has some identity to elliptic functions similar to how the q-Pochhammer symbol includes the pentagonal numbers for its sum. I don't know how to evaluate this sum further. Any help or solutions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe a variant of the Pentagonal Number Theorem could help? I.e. you could express it as an evaluation of a Jacobi Triple Product.

Comment: Mathematica yields the following closed form in terms of Jacobi theta functions: $$1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}=2^{-7/8}\vartheta_2(0,1/\sqrt{2}).$$ (This really just follows from the definition $\vartheta_2(z,q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{(n+1/2)^2} e^{(2n+1)iz}$ using $n(n+1)/2 = (n+1/2)^2-1/4$ and symmetry.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Nice! That answers the question. Thank you